# Linking last cell in a column of a different sheet, even if it is a word

Tags: google-sheets

I've read how to link the last # in a column into a cell on a different sheet using:
=index(sheet2!d:d, match(1e99, sheet2!d:d)). Thank you to whoever posted it.  I also have a need to link the last entry (a word) in a column in a different sheet.  Any thoughts on how to do that?  I tried tinkering with this formula but can't figuire it out.

Also, can I format the linked cell by color if the word is 'Make" versus leaving it black if the word is 'OK'.

I've tried googling it and looking at various forums.  I was successful in applying the formulas I found to numbers, but not to text, as described above.  I suspected that would be the case because I didn't know how to change the formula.

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return the lowest none-numeric value cell from a column that is not blank.

`=let(zRa,Sheet2!A:A,cleanData,filter(zRa,if(zRa<>"",not(isnumber(zRa)))),chooseRows(cleanData,rows(cleandata)))`

Obviously swap in the correct sheet and column for the second parameter.

For the formatting question, look up Conditional Formatting with google sheets. There's no doubt hundreds of demos and videos on this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: K. yeah welcome and all, umm, maybe click `accept`?